# Conditional operator with DataBinder.Eval

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I want to do something like this

```
<%#(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Age").ToString()=="0") 
    ?"n/a"
    :"DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Age")"%>
```

is it possible?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 10):

You can write a Method on page level and format the output there.

eg

```
<%# GetAgeDisplay(Eval("Age")) %>
```

and in code behind:

```
public String GetAgeDisplay(Int16 age) {
  return age == 0 ? "n/a" : String.Format("{0}", age );
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you are calling `DataBinder` instead of simply returning a string:

Change this:

```
<%#(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Age").ToString()=="0") ? 
             "n/a":"DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Age")"%>
```

To:

```
<%#(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Age").ToString()=="0") ? 
             "n/a":DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Age")%>
```

What you are doing is returning a string instead of executing the binding expression.